# Sending boolean to Pebble with PebbleKit

Tags: android, c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I've never really done much C and am a bit stumped on the best way to send a boolean from an Android app to the Pebble Watch.

I have strings working fine, but there doesn't seem to be an addBoolean method on PebbleDictionary. As a work around I am trying to use addUint8 to send a 1 or 0, but am having trouble handling the message on the Pebble.

Here is my Android code:

```
    PebbleDictionary data = new PebbleDictionary();
    if (isGPSFix()){
        data.addUint8(GPS_HAS_FIX_KEY, Byte.valueOf("1"));
    } else {
        data.addUint8(GPS_HAS_FIX_KEY, Byte.valueOf("0"));
    }
    PebbleKit.sendDataToPebble(app.getContext(), UUID, data);
```

And in my Pebble I have a data struct:

```
static struct MyData {
  uint8_t haveGPS[1];
  .... // other stuff ommitted
  AppSync sync;
  uint8_t sync_buffer[256];
} s_data;
```

And then I am trying to compare it like this in my sync_tuple_changed callback.

```
static void sync_tuple_changed_callback(const uint32_t key, const Tuple* new_tuple, const Tuple* old_tuple, void* context) {
(void) old_tuple;

   switch (key) {
     case GPS_HAS_FIX_KEY:
       if (memcmp(s_data.haveGPS, new_tuple->value->data, 8) == 0){
         memcpy(s_data.haveGPS,new_tuple->value->data, new_tuple->length);
         vibes_short_pulse();
       }
     break;
     default:
       return;
   }
 }
```

The watch doesn't crash, it just never vibrates when the phone drops or acquires GPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things look good on the Android side. I think this is more of an AppSync problem.

Here are a few things to check in the watch application:

- Make sure you create a list of tuples with initial values on the watch. This list needs to to contain your key `GPS_HAS_FIX_KEY`;

```
￼Tuplet initial_values[] = {
  TupletInteger(GPS_HAS_FIX_KEY, (uint8_t) 0),
  /* Other tuplets that you will synchronize */
};
```

- Make sure you pass those tuplets to the `app_sync_init()` function:

```
app_sync_init(&sync, sync_buffer, sizeof(sync_buffer),
              initial_values, ARRAY_LENGTH(initial_values),
              sync_tuple_changed_callback, sync_error_callback, NULL);
```

Those two steps are required for app_sync to work (cf [AppSync reference documentation](http://developer.getpebble.com/sdkref/group___app_sync.html)).

Comment: Thanks @sarfata. I was missing the entry in the initial values Tuplet.
I haven't quite got the memcmp quite right, but if I just notify on every update, I am at least now getting vibrations.

Comment: I now have the compare logic working correctly too. See my answer below for working memcmp and memcpy commands.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you have to send an Dictionary of keys and objects to the watch. In Objective C it looks like this:

```
NSDictionary *update = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
```

Keys are all integer and objects I would think can be of Boolean. In my case only String what works well.

In a loop I perform something like this on the watch:

```
t=dict_find(received,count);
strcpy(strs[count], dict_find(received,count)->value->cstring);
```

But I have to tell you that I am still a rookie.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to sarfata's accepted answer above, I found that I had not added this new item to the Tuple that the Pebble was expecting.

Once I added that, my switch statement started working and I just had to get the memory compare to work. Here is the working code for my memory compare in case it helps anyone.

```
case GPS_HAS_FIX_KEY:
if (memcmp(s_data.haveGPS, new_tuple->value->data, 1) != 0){
  memcpy(s_data.haveGPS,new_tuple->value->data, 1);
  vibes_short_pulse();
}
break;
```

It really was a simple as expecting one byte (not 8 bytes - I thought it was doing a bit compare) and negating the logic for the case where the new value is NOT like the old one.